# Why is the urls.py file not created automatically?

Tags: django

Almost every video which I saw about Django (for beginners), people who create applications using the startapp command and add their `urls.py` file manually in their application. My question is, if urls.py is so important for views and for our app why it's not creating automatically when we run startapp command!

Comment: What will "trigger" your views otherwise? A HTTP request to a given path will let Django look into the urls, and then trigger the corresponding view. One can not automatically derive `urls.py`, since that usually scales with the views you make.

Comment: This question might be better asked of the core django team.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Not every app directly serves the end user**

URLs.py is only useful for routing users to pages which primarily have to do with that app. However, many apps may only do internal things. I have an app in one of my projects that handles badges and rewards, but there is no page which corresponds to any of that because it all shows exclusively as part of the profile pages (and the routing is handled within the profile app).

It just isn't always needed and that is why it is not always included.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you don't have to serve each of your app to the end-users. You may have apps responsible for only your inner interactions. So it is not logical to put urls.py in each and every app.

Answer (score 1):

It vary on how you use your routing. 
django give project wide urls.py by default when you create the project using `django-admin startproject` command. so you can create all your project's urls on this file.
And not all app intended to server user directly using urls.

Whether i also prefer to create separate urls.py and api-urls.py routers for every app and include in main urls.py